# Nested Promise Chain Handling? (Promise.then( new Promise))?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bluebird, es6-promise

How Can I Handle promise in promise?

sql stands for Sequelize.

```
asyncFunc1                 //(sql.findOne)
.then(
  (res1)=>asyncFunc2(res1) //(sql.findOrCreate - must end with spread)
  .spread(
      (res2)=>{            // **Must** Use asyncFunc2's Result value.
         var newAsyncFunc1 = Promise.resolve(res2);
         var newAsyncFunc2 = Promise.resolve(res2);
         Promise.all([newAsyncFunc1,newAsyncFunc2])
      }
      .then(() => asyncFunc3(res1,res2)) //(sql.findOrCreate)
  ))                       // **Must** Use asyncFunc1, 2's Result value.
.spread((res3) => asyncFunc4(res3);
```

--------------------------(added 17.05.24)----------------------------

For more detailed explanation,

outer variables are `parentId, childName, distance`,

```
User.findOne({where:{id:parentId}})                 
.then(                                //default is for creating rows
  (res1)=>User.findOrCreate({where:{name:childName},default:{depth:res1.get('depth')+1}})
  .spread(
      (res2)=>{                       //Create Msg Send to Users.
         var msgHeader = Promise.resolve(res2); //also Async like findOne.
         var msgBody = Promise.resolve(res2); //also Async like findOne.
         Promise.all([msgHeader,msgBody]).then((resMsg)=>{
             var message = {header:resMsg[0],body:resMsg[1]};
             messageTxQueue.append[message];
         }
      }
      .then(() => Family.findOrCreate(res1,res2))
  ))                  
.spread((res3) => Family.update({where:{id:res3},default:{distance:distance});
```

findOrCreate Document. (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOrCreate)  (used Bluebird `.spread` - No big diffrence with ES6 `.then`)

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html

--------------------------(added 17.05.24)----------------------------

Why I nested `.then(() => asyncFunc3(res1,res2))` under `(res2)=>{}` is to pass `res2` value over next function.

And What I want to achieve is, I really want to run `.then(() => asyncFunc3(res1,res2))` this right after `return Promise.all(newAsyncFunc)`.

So The running sequence will be like 
`asyncFunc -> asyncFunc2 -> Promise.all(newAsyncFunc) -> .then(asyncFunc3) -> asyncFunc4`

But this code works like this. `asyncFunc -> asyncFunc2 -> asyncFunc3 -> asyncFunc4 ........(far after)-> Promise.all(newAsyncFunc)`

What's the problem with my code?
why this code doesn't chained as I wanted?

(sorry for my js coding.. I'm newbie here)

Comment: Why are you chaining `.then(() => asyncFunc3(res1,res2))` to the arrow function, not the the `spread(…)` call promise? That should throw an exception.

Comment: `var newAsyncFunc = Promise.resolve(res2) … Promise.all(newAsyncFunc)` makes no sense. `Promise.all` takes an array, not a promise. And `Promise.resolve` doesn't return a function.

Comment: Can you post your actual code, please? I can't see how in the world this would execute `asyncFunc3` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've updated my code.

I'd like those `(res2) => {}` part to be done before  `.then(() => asyncFunc3(res1,res2))`.

Can I make this sequence as I desired to?

Comment: The code you posted still has a "`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`". Please fix that first